# Pulling directories and files from a website via http in VB

Tags: vb.net, list, server, directory

I have a website that is basically just a file repository, and I want others to be able to download these files via a nice VB application. The networking side of VB is a little foreign to me, so I'm having trouble grasping the intricacies. Basically, I want to pull the directory and file information (names and paths are all that's needed at first) into a tree view in my application (given a base directory).

A month ago I had this working fully, but today, without changing any of my code, the methods I was using are now throwing an exception at me. At this point, I'm willing to re-write this part to make it cleaner and more reliable, but I need some guidance on the best way to do this, starting from the function called when I click my button to show the listing.

Initially, I was getting a string and breaking it into an array, but for some reason, the GetStringAsync line is now throwing a "the remote party has closed the transport stream" exception at me. But even if someone knew how to fix this issue, I want a more reliable and robust way to iterate over all the directories in a "list directories" website. The line is shown below just for illustration. This function is being awaited in another that catches the exception. I didn't show any of the parsing that happens later since it fails immediately upon the request.

```
Public Async Function GetRemoteFileInfos(remoteAddress As String) As Task(Of IEnumerable(Of RemoteFileInfo))
Dim results As New List(Of RemoteFileInfo)
Dim htmlText As String

Using client As New HttpClient
  htmlText = Await client.GetStringAsync(remoteAddress)


End Using

Return results.ToArray
```

Maybe I'm just misunderstanding the async flow, which is why I'd like to start over anyway, and have some more experienced programmers guide me through perhaps a basic understanding of how this part of the program needs to function. Note, I don't want to use FTP, I'd like to not force users to install any extra plugins, and the base directory is https://update.nerfarena.net/.

Comment: did you try adding browser information to make it look like you are using mozilla or something else? The server probably drops the connection because you are missing a valid browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with my web host about the issue, they told me to make sure the security protocol I was using was TLS 1.1 or 1.2 as 1.0 had been disabled on the host platform. A quick search yielded some ways to opt in to newer TLS versions, and the one that seems to be working for me now is:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

Thanks everyone for all the help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

This works well. Now for getting the information out of the string I leave this to you.

```
    Dim httpc As New HttpClient
    httpc.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml")
    httpc.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0")
    Dim response As String = Await (httpc.GetStringAsync("https://update.nerfarena.net/"))
```

Comment: Okay, but as for getting the information out of the string, I want to make sure I'm making the right assumptions. The data I get back from the request is all the files and folders in the URL I supplied right? So, in other words, if there's folders within folders, I have to GetStringAsync each folder (maybe in some recursive method) in order to fully explore each one, right?

Comment: I just found out that using the https protocol instead of http causes the exception. Now, if I knew why...

Comment: doesn't matter https or not. you should include it. some firewall will refuse connection if you are missing headers and stuff. Always include them. It also dictates what format the data should be returned. Yes you would have to recursively go to each folder. Same thing as ftp. You could create a cache and update the cache when the user open folders

Comment: So I wrote the recursive folder listing function and it works great in conjunction with the improvements to request. However, it only works in http. I'd prefer to be more secure, and use https, but again, that is what throws the exception. It works 100% until I add that little "s". So does anyone know what could be going on there? I assume I'm overlooking some security intricacy.

Comment: @Rajada works fine for me in https. Must be something with your code. Try these 4 lines in a new project and look at response....it contains the page.

Comment: I did as you suggested, and it still throws the exception. So let's say somehow, it's not my code, but my network or my computer or perhaps VS environment. The inner exception is "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected Error occurred On a send." Any advice?

Comment: @Rajada this doesn't mean much. Yes it could be your environment. You have no problems opening the link using https in a regular browser?

Comment: Yes, no problem opening it in a browser.

Comment: Some of my other testers have the same issue, but not all of them. Wondering what the common factor is, as it's clearly not just my setup.